# find max duplicate values in a list

Tags: python

I have a file containing multiple lines in format student code and followed by some answer. e.g

```
N00000047,B,,D,C,C,B,D,D,C,C,D,,A,B,D,C,,D,A,C,,D,B,D,C
N00000048,B,A,D,D,C,B,,D,C,C,D,B,A,B,A,D,B,D,A,C,A,A,B,D,D
N00000049,A,,D,D,C,B,D,,C,C,D,B,,B,A,C,C,D,A,C,A,A,B,D,D
N00000050,,C,,D,,D,D,A,C,A,A,B,A,B,A,D,B,D,A,C,D,A,B,D,D
N00000051,B,A,B,,C,B,D,A,C,C,D,D,A,B,A,C,B,C,A,,A,A,B,D,B
N00000052,B,A,D,D,,B,D,A,D,,D,B,A,B,A,C,B,C,A,C,A,A,B,D,D
N00000053,B,A,D,D,C,B,D,A,C,C,D,B,B,B,C,C,B,D,A,C,A,C,A,D,D
```

And now I have to find which is the most question was skipped by students by order which question, how many student skipped and how many % student skipped that question.

I was split then make a loop and add every entry of skipped question in a list and then got stuck in find the max duplicates values in a list (it can be more than 1 output).
This is some expected output:
`Question that most people answer incorrectly: 10 - 4 - 0.20, 14 - 4 - 0.20, 16 - 4 - 0.20, 19 - 4 - 0.20, 22 - 4 - 0.20`. In format : a - b - c which a is question number, b is how much student was skipped, c is it take how many percentage of total student in class. There are 3 question have the most skipped is 10, 14, 19 and 22 and they all have 4 skipped.

Edited:
I put all skipped question in a list and count for which question have a largest duplicate like this:

```
def find_max_count(list):
    item_with_max_count = []
    max_count = 0
    for item in list:
        item_count = list.count(item)
        if  item_count > max_count:
            max_count = list.count
    for item1 in list:
        if list.count(item1) == max_count:
            item_with_max_count.append(item1)
    return item_with_max_count
```

but there is an error:
`TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'builtin_function_or_method'`

Comment: Can you please show what exactly should be the result in this example?

Comment: This is some expected output:
Question that most people answer incorrectly: 10 - 4 - 0.20, 14 - 4 - 0.20, 16 - 4 - 0.20, 19 - 4 - 0.20, 22 - 4 - 0.20.
in format : a - b - c
which a is question number, 4 is how much student was skipped, 0.20 is it take 20% of total student in class

Comment: 1) Add this information in properly formatted form to your question 1) Where are getting the question number? 2) Answered incorrectly and skipped question are not the same thing. What are you looking for and how do you define it?

Comment: Please show the code you have attempted. It doesn't work, clearly, but it will give us a much greater insight into where you need help that describing what you're tried. Don't tell. _Show._

Comment: sorry, there a a set of correct answer. But what I really focus right now is only find the most skipped question by students.

Comment: Please edit your question to include code, as you cannot format properly in a comment.

Comment: Im already add some explain, hope it work.

Answer (score 0):

Start by accumulating a dictionary of all responses to each question and a list of all skipped answers:

```
from collections import defaultdict

responses = defaultdict(list) # all responses to a given question
skipped = []                  # all skiped answers
for record in data.splitlines():
    student_id, *answers = record.split(',')
    for question_number, answer in enumerate(answers, start=1):
        responses[question_number].append(answer)
        if answer == '':
           skipped.append(question_number)
```

Next perform the analysis:

```
from statistics import multimode

print('Most skipped questions:', multimode(skipped))
print('Answer for questions with more than two or more skips')
for question, answers in responses.items():
    if answers.count('') >= 2:
        print(f'Question {question}: {answers}')
```

This outputs:

```
Most skipped questions: [2, 5]
Answer for questions with more than two or more skips
Question 2: ['', 'A', '', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A']
Question 5: ['C', 'C', 'C', '', 'C', '', 'C']
```

I'm certain this is what you wanted (a target output wasn't shown), but this should get you started the key techniques for analysis.  In particular, the [multimode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.multimode) function is super helpful in identifying most frequent occurrences including ties for first place.  Also [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is super useful for transposing the data from answers by student to answers by question.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe my English may not good. What i want to find is the most skipped question and its can be more than two output. Like there are 5 question have the most skipped is 3

Comment: @HàVănPhước I still can't tell what you mean.  Please provide a sample output.  Also, I've shown the main functions that you can use.  Try those.

Comment: Yeah, I already put some output format example. Maybe its not a correct answer but hope its could help

Answer (score 0):

Let's get a dictionary with the student id and the answers.

```
data = """
N00000047,B,,D,C,C,B,D,D,C,C,D,,A,B,D,C,,D,A,C,,D,B,D,C
N00000048,B,A,D,D,C,B,,D,C,C,D,B,A,B,A,D,B,D,A,C,A,A,B,D,D
N00000049,A,,D,D,C,B,D,,C,C,D,B,,B,A,C,C,D,A,C,A,A,B,D,D
N00000050,,C,,D,,D,D,A,C,A,A,B,A,B,A,D,B,D,A,C,D,A,B,D,D
N00000051,B,A,B,,C,B,D,A,C,C,D,D,A,B,A,C,B,C,A,,A,A,B,D,B
N00000052,B,A,D,D,,B,D,A,D,,D,B,A,B,A,C,B,C,A,C,A,A,B,D,D
N00000053,B,A,D,D,C,B,D,A,C,C,D,B,B,B,C,C,B,D,A,C,A,C,A,D,D
"""

info = {s: a 
        for line in data.strip().split('\n') 
        for s, *a in [line.split(',')]}
# {'N00000047': ['B', '', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'D', '', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'C', '', 'D', 'A', 'C', '', 'D', 'B', 'D', 'C'], 
#  'N00000048': ['B', 'A', 'D', 'D', 'C', 'B', '', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'D'],
#  'N00000049': ['A', '', 'D', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'D', '', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'B', '', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'D'],
#  'N00000050': ['', 'C', '', 'D', '', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'D'],
#  'N00000051': ['B', 'A', 'B', '', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A', '', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'B'],
#  'N00000052': ['B', 'A', 'D', 'D', '', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'D', '', 'D', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'D'],
#  'N00000053': ['B', 'A', 'D', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'D']}
```

Now, we can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count up answers.

```
from collections import Counter

info = {s: Counter(a) 
        for line in data.strip().split('\n') 
        for s, *a in [line.split(',')]}
# {'N00000047': Counter({'D': 8, 'C': 7, 'B': 4, '': 4, 'A': 2}),
#  'N00000048': Counter({'D': 8, 'B': 6, 'A': 6, 'C': 4, '': 1}),
#  'N00000049': Counter({'D': 7, 'C': 6, 'A': 5, 'B': 4, '': 3}),
#  'N00000050': Counter({'D': 8, 'A': 7, 'B': 4, '': 3, 'C': 3}),
#  'N00000051': Counter({'B': 7, 'A': 7, 'C': 5, 'D': 4, '': 2}),
#  'N00000052': Counter({'A': 7, 'D': 7, 'B': 6, 'C': 3, '': 2}),
#  'N00000053': Counter({'D': 7, 'C': 7, 'B': 6, 'A': 5})}
```

From here, finding the statistical data you're looking for should be much easier. For instance:

*(Requires Python 3.8+ for `:=` operator.)*

```
{q: {'all':        (c := Counter(a)), 
     'skipped':    (s := c['']), 
     'percentage': s / len(a)} 
 for line in data.strip().split('\n') 
 for q, *a in [line.split(',')]}
# {'N00000047': {'all': Counter({'D': 8, 'C': 7, 'B': 4, '': 4, 'A': 2}), 'skipped': 4, 'percentage': 0.16}, 
#  'N00000048': {'all': Counter({'D': 8, 'B': 6, 'A': 6, 'C': 4, '': 1}), 'skipped': 1, 'percentage': 0.04}, 
#  'N00000049': {'all': Counter({'D': 7, 'C': 6, 'A': 5, 'B': 4, '': 3}), 'skipped': 3, 'percentage': 0.12}, 
#  'N00000050': {'all': Counter({'D': 8, 'A': 7, 'B': 4, '': 3, 'C': 3}), 'skipped': 3, 'percentage': 0.12}, 
#  'N00000051': {'all': Counter({'B': 7, 'A': 7, 'C': 5, 'D': 4, '': 2}), 'skipped': 2, 'percentage': 0.08}, 
#  'N00000052': {'all': Counter({'A': 7, 'D': 7, 'B': 6, 'C': 3, '': 2}), 'skipped': 2, 'percentage': 0.08}, 
#  'N00000053': {'all': Counter({'D': 7, 'C': 7, 'B': 6, 'A': 5}), 'skipped': 0, 'percentage': 0.0}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like?:

```
cat skipped.csv                                                                                                                                                           
N00000047,B,,D,C,C,B,D,D,C,C,D,,A,B,D,C,,D,A,C,,D,B,D,C
N00000048,B,A,D,D,C,B,,D,C,C,D,B,A,B,A,D,B,D,A,C,A,A,B,D,D
N00000049,A,,D,D,C,B,D,,C,C,D,B,,B,A,C,C,D,A,C,A,A,B,D,D
N00000050,,C,,D,,D,D,A,C,A,A,B,A,B,A,D,B,D,A,C,D,A,B,D,D
N00000051,B,A,B,,C,B,D,A,C,C,D,D,A,B,A,C,B,C,A,,A,A,B,D,B
N00000052,B,A,D,D,,B,D,A,D,,D,B,A,B,A,C,B,C,A,C,A,A,B,D,D
N00000053,B,A,D,D,C,B,D,A,C,C,D,B,B,B,C,C,B,D,A,C,A,C,A,D,D

import csv 
from collections import Counter

with open("skipped.csv", "r" , newline="") as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    l = []
    for line in reader:
        d = {"q": line.pop(0)}
        ct = Counter(line)
        # In Python 3.10+ you can do ct.total() instead of below.
        q_sum = sum(ct.values())
        skipped = ct['']         
        perc = skipped/q_sum
        d.update({"skipped": skipped, "percentage": perc})
        l.append(d)
    l.sort(key=lambda x: x['skipped'], reverse=True)

l
[{'q': 'N00000047', 'skipped': 4, 'percentage': 0.16},
 {'q': 'N00000049', 'skipped': 3, 'percentage': 0.12},
 {'q': 'N00000050', 'skipped': 3, 'percentage': 0.12},
 {'q': 'N00000051', 'skipped': 2, 'percentage': 0.08},
 {'q': 'N00000052', 'skipped': 2, 'percentage': 0.08},
 {'q': 'N00000048', 'skipped': 1, 'percentage': 0.04},
 {'q': 'N00000053', 'skipped': 0, 'percentage': 0.0}]
```